# Why doesn't Workspace Switcher Icon appear in Launcher?

Tags: launcher, workspace-switcher

I am new to Ubuntu, and the Workspace concept intrigues me.  Using Help, I find that there is an Icon for the Workspace Switcher, and it is not where the help document says it should be. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the workspace-switcher is not enabled in the Launcher. This setting is toggleable via the Appearance - Behaviour tab in System Settings

Untick the option to remove the workspace-switcher icon.